# How to memcpy a part of a two dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

How to memcpy the two dimensional array in C:

I have a two dimensional array:

```
int a[100][100];

int c[10][10];
```

I want to use `memcpy` to copy the all the values in array c to array a, how to do this using memcpy?

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    memcpy(&a[i][10], c, sizeof(c));
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: That depends on where you want the values to go. It looks like not quite what you probably want.

Comment: You have 100 times the capacity in `a`.  Which elements of `a` do you want to hold a copy of `c`?

Comment: More like `sizeof(c[i])`, non?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That should work :

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    memcpy(&a[i], &c[i], sizeof(c[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should actually be:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
{
  memcpy(&(a[i][0]), &(c[i][0]), 10 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: when I try to do &(c[i][0]), it tells me that error: no match for 'operator[]' in '*(c+ 924u)[0]'

Comment: You sure you typed it right? My compiler tells me nothing.. Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's correct, no.

There's no way for `memcpy()` to know about the in-memory layout of `a` and "respect" it, it will overwrite `sizeof c` adjacent bytes which might not be what you mean.

If you want to copy into a "sub-square" of `a`, then you must do so manually.